# How to restrict NSLog to print using boolean variable

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new to the iPhone development. I have too many NSLog statements in my code. When ever I want than only the nslog has to print in console. How can I do that?

Comment: What have u tried so far?? ur CODE?

Comment: This same question came up yesterday.  Search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code in your pch file, and set your bool value according to it... like in which ever class you are using declare this `BOOL myDebugEnabled = FALSE;`

```
extern BOOL myDebugEnabled;
#define DLog(fmt, ...) if (myDebugEnabled) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```